# Normed space but not complete

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

As someone pointed out this could seems to be a duplicate of another question already posted. Is in fact the same question but I have provided also the effort of the solution and additionally I have shown something else, for instante the proof of the triangular inequality via de Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Hence is definetly a duplicate but with a better description of the problem and the solution.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ open and bounded and let $\mathcal{A}=\{ v \in C^{2}(\overline{\Omega}) \, | \,v=0\, on \, \partial\Omega\}$ with the following scalar product

\begin{equation}
(u,v)_{\mathcal{A}}=\int_{\Omega} (\nabla u, \nabla v)_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}dx
\end{equation}
where $(\cdot, \cdot)_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$ is the canonical scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I have to prove that $(\mathcal{A}, \| \cdot \|_{\mathcal{A}})$ is a normed space but not a Banach space, where $\| u \|_{\mathcal{A}}=\sqrt{(u,u)_{\mathcal{A}}}$. Proving that $(\mathcal{A}, \| \cdot \|_{\mathcal{A}})$ is a normed space is quite straightforward, the only point that make me think was the triangular inequality that I solved using the Chauchy-Schwarz inequality, namely
\begin{equation}
|(u,v)_{\mathcal{A}}|\leq \|u\|_{\mathcal{A}}\|v\|_{\mathcal{A}},
\end{equation}
infact if I consider $\| u+v\|_{\mathcal{A}}^2$ I can proced in this way
\begin{split}
\| u+v\|_{\mathcal{A}}^2= & \| u\|_{\mathcal{A}}^2+2(u,v)_{\mathcal{A}} +\|v\|_{\mathcal{A}}^2 \\
\leq &\| u\|_{\mathcal{A}}^2+2\|u\|_{\mathcal{A}}\|v\|_{\mathcal{A}} +\|v\|_{\mathcal{A}}^2 \\
= & (\| u\|_{\mathcal{A}}+\|v\|_{\mathcal{A}})^2
\end{split}
Hence we have proved $\| u+v\|_{\mathcal{A}}\leq \| u\|_{\mathcal{A}}+\|v\|_{\mathcal{A}} $.

But I was stucked on the noncompleteness, I tried to argue as following but I am not sure if it is right. Let $n=1$ and $\Omega=(-1,1)$ and suppose to take the sequence $(u_n)_n\subset \mathcal{A}$, given by

\begin{equation}
u_n=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}},
\end{equation}

I can notice that $u_n \rightarrow u$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ using for instance the uniform norm, where $u=1-|x|$ that does not belong to $\mathcal{A}$. Hence I found a sequence that converges to an element that is not in the space and consequentely $\mathcal{A}$ is not complete.

Comment: I do not think so, for some reasons. Firtsly for me the answer at that question was not satisfying at all. Secondly i asked something else and I provided an effort to prove it.

Comment: I also agree that this is not a duplicate since you are asking whether a specific sequence $(u_n)_n$ is a counterexample. On what $\Omega$ is your sequence defined?

Comment: Well, actually you can take any interval where is not missing the element $0$ when $n=1$ and adjust the sequence as you take different interval, for the sequence i have chosen is better to take $\Omega=(-1,1)$.

Comment: But $u_n(1)$ should be equal to zero, not $1$...

Comment: @RobH you're right $u_{n} \notin \mathcal{A}$, so I am wondering if i adjust the interval in some way(or the sequence to make it belonging to $\mathcal{A}$. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Giovanni Of course, you're right. I meant $u_n(1)\neq 0$. Sorry. 
Do you know the concept of [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)? 
It is "easy" to prove the theorem using convolutions.

Comment: The reason why the normed space isn't closed, is that the norm doesn't take the second derivative in account. That means you can converge in the first derivative, but you don't need to converge in the second. Thus you can converge to a function only being continuously differentiable once.

Comment: @RobH yes, I know the concept of convolution but even thinking about I cannot prove it.

Comment: I did not notice about the problem on the norm that take in account only the first derivative. Anyway I thought that I can modify the sequence $u_n$ as $\sqrt{1+1/n^2)-\sqrt{x^2+1/n^2)$, now it should works. Am I right?

Comment: I think that example works! 
$u_n'\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{(1/n^2+x^2)}}\longrightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty}= \frac{x}{\left\vert x\right\vert}$, which is not conintuous. There is no function in $f\in C^2$ with $\nabla f\left(x\right)= \frac{x}{\left\vert x\right\vert}$, so $u_n$ is a cauchy-seqence in $\mathcal{A}$ that doesn't converge.

Comment: @RobH i have noticed that i have writen the function badly.  Let me rewrite $u_n=\sqrt{1+1/n^2}-\sqrt{x^2+1/n^2}$ and the derivative is $u_n'=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1/n^2}}$(that is the one you've written with the minus in front of the fraction).

Comment: right! still works..

Comment: Post the solution as solution below the question and the the comments can be deleted.

Comment: Done! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the space $(\mathcal{A}, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}})$ is that the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}}$ takes in account only the first derivative of the function, but the set $\mathcal{A}$ is the space of the functions with continuous second derivative that annihilate on the border of $\Omega$.

Hence we can put ourselves in the situation in which $n=1$ and $\Omega=(-1,1)$, hence the set $\mathcal{A}$ becomes $\{ v \in C^{2}([-1,1]) \, | \,v(x)=0\, when \, x=-1,1 \}$. Thus is enough to find a sequence that converges to a function that has the first derivative not continuous. Firstly I thought it was enough to take such a sequence

\begin{equation}
u_n(x)=1-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}},
\end{equation}
but $u_n \notin \mathcal{A}$ because for instance $u_1(1)=1-\sqrt{2}\ne 0$. Hence I can adjust $u_n$ to find a sequence $(v_n)_n\subset \mathcal{A}$ that $v_n\notin C^{1}([-1,1])$. So I can use the following sequence

\begin{equation}
v_n(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}.
\end{equation}

$(v_n)_n\subset \mathcal{A}$ in fact $(v_n)_n\subset C^{2}([-1,1])$ and annihilate itself in $x=-1,1$. But $v_{n}$ converges to $v=1-|x|$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. As we know the function $v$ has the following derivative

\begin{equation}
v(x)=-\frac{x}{|x|},
\end{equation} 
that is not continuous since is not defined in $x=0$ and there is a leap from the left to the right limit.

Consequently we have found a counter example, and we can conclude that the space $(\mathcal{A}, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}})$ is a normed space but is not a Banach space because is not complete, namely there exists a sequence contained in $\mathcal{A}$ that converges to an element not in $\mathcal{A}$.